# Formatting date cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to clean some data in excel but cannot make it use the Date as a string/text. Instead it inserts the date as numbers, see below.
I have tried copying into notepad, pasting into excel as text. Make a cell with =1*B2, and then adding this. But same result!

Original:

```
Timestamp   Date    Data1 Data2
1539808680  2018-10-17 15:38    498 506
```

Formula:

```
=B2&";"&C2&";"&D2
```

Result:

```
Date;Data1;Data2
43390.6513888889;498;506
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the date value in the [text function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60096&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

```
=TEXT(B2;"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

So:

```
=TEXT(B2;"YYYY-MM-DD")&";"&C2&";"&D2
```

"YYYY-MM-DD" is a bit tricky... it's different depending on your regional settings. easiest way to find what you have is to right click on your cell date and choose "Format Cells":

[image]

Go down to Custom and the appropriate date combination. So in my excel version, which is nordic, I need to use: `=TEXT(C3;"ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD")` to get it right.

[image]

Notice that I use "`;`" as delimiter. While US probably would use "`,`".

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Comment: I'm very curious as to what platform uses `1539808680` to represent `018-10-17 15:38`. Could you offer suggestions?

Comment: @Jeeped - it's my own .js code for an IoT sensor which saves it like that! Epoch timestamp.